# datastructure for a chain in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have requirement where I need to maintain a path of coordinates(x,y) for a particular cell in a matrix

for eg

(1,2) => (2,1), (3,1),(4,1)

which essentially means  (2,1) is the predecessor of (1,2) and
(3,1) is the predecessor of (2,1) and (4,1) is the    predecessor of (3,1)

To achieve this I need a data structure in Javascript

What I did was to create a map which will store each coordinate and its predecessor

so I defined an object

```
function MyType(coords, val) {
      this.coords = coords;
      this.val = val;
    }

    function Couple(x, y) {

      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
    }
```

and I store the MyType Objects in the map

Comment: @thefourtheye The key will be the MyType object

Comment: Then what is `element`?

Comment: Keys must be strings, unless you have a type specifically designed to allow objects.  If you try to use anything else as a key in a normal Object, it will be converted to a string first...and unless you've designed your key-type otherwise, the string will be `"[object Object]"` (or perhaps `"[object Couple]"`, i forget.  But either way, it won't be useful as a key.)

Comment: @thefourtheye I will use the "element" as key which is of MyType object

Comment: @cHao yes I want to use the MyType Object as the key

Comment: Then you need to give it a `.toString()` method that returns a unique string for a given set of values.  A string representation of the contents, or a hash code, or some other string that can identify the object later.  Cause right now, the only key your map will end up containing is `"[object Object]"`.

Comment: You mean `var value = map[key]`?

Comment: @FelixKling  yes ...the value should of MyTypeObject

Comment: @sameerkarjatkar: Wait...the *key* should be a MyType, or the *value*?

Comment: @cHao  u mean when I say some var val = map[key] where key is MyTypeObject the val will contain a string representation and I have to convert it again to MyType object

Comment: I mean that if you say `var a = {}; var b = { foo: 'whee' }; a[b] = 42; console.dir(a);`, you'll see one property, named `"[object Object]"`, with a value of 42.  Good luck converting `[object Object]` back into something useful.  The only shot you have is to give `b` (or its prototype) a `toString` method that returns some string that identifies the object.  Then the key you see will be that string.  (You still might not be able to convert it back.  But what you *can* do is build another object  that'll have the same representation and use it to look up the value again.)

Comment: As for the conversion part (and this is only useful if you don't mind two objects with the same values ending up as the same key), you could have two objects, one for keys and one for values.  Once `toString()` returns something useful, you can say like `keys[key] = key; values[key] = value;`.  That's about as close as you're going to get to a reasonably-performing object-to-object map that doesn't simply forget the key *objects* ever existed.  (It's all kinda unnecessary, though, unless you really *need* the key objects back.)

Comment: @cHao I guess I am not using the correct data structure here . what I want is that each Coord(x,y) will hold a another Coord(x,y) and so on

Comment: So, umm, why not just *do* that?  Set a (consistently named) property of your first Coord to the other one.  No need for a map, if you're actually saying here what you mean.

Comment: @cHao  In a sense when I say (x,y) i want a set of pairs (x1,y1),(x2,y2), (x3,y3)

Comment: OK, you're all but redefining everything arbitrarily here.  How bout this: edit your answer, start from the beginning, and tell us -- precisely -- about the *root problem* you are trying to solve.  Don't assume a map is the answer; don't assume anything is the answer. Just state the problem, and mention the map thingie you've tried so far and the problems you've run into with it.

Comment: So in your example, if (1,2) => (2,1), (3,1),(4,1) ... does that also mean (2,1) => (3,1),(4,1), and (3,1) => (4,1)?  Or is any particular path entirely unrelated to the paths for other locations?

Comment: Why don't you use an array to keep the coordinates in a sequence. Or better just set the predecessor on the object's "next" property.  `coords1.next = coords2`

Comment: @cHao yes so when I say (1,2) ....I should get the entire chain

Comment: @gp. ok ..how do I navigate ? I mean suppose I say give me the path for (1,2)